# Facebook API OAuthException: “An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later” when trying to retrieve a Page-specific access token

Tags: api, authentication, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I want my app to be able to post status updates to a specific Page. I've got an application set up and retrieved its app ID, and I'm following the the “Page Login” section at the bottom of the Facebook authentication documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

The first stage (user granting the app the `manage_page` permission) seems to work perfectly. I get redirected to a URL like this:

`http://myapp.com/#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&expires_in=6483`

The docs then say you should access the following:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE`

replacing `TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE` with the one returned by the previous request, and this should return “a list of all the Pages the user administers including Page specific access token for each Page”.

However, it doesn't. All I get is the following JSON response:

```js
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
        "type": "OAuthException"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Could I have set something up incorrectly when creating the application? The error message is less than helpful, so any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: 'Unexpected error' = server side error; does the access token you have work for other calls? (e.g. /me/permissions)
Also, you can retrieve the page access token with a request to /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token

Comment: No, the key doesn't seems to work for other calls either - I tried `/me/permissions` and got the same error. If I visit `https://graph.facebook.com/MYPAGEID?fields=access_token` I just get `false` returned. No JSON, just `false`. I presume that was the right URL? I tried to look it up but Facebook's [API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) are currently unavailable due to a server error...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/status/dashboard/ currently shows "We are currently experiencing issues that may cause some API requests to take longer or fail unexpectedly. We are investigating the issue and working on a resolution."

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just suddenly started working this morning—no idea why.

Comment: Well, random downvoter, that's what happened. What did you *want* me to write?

Comment: Ahah nice response. Also I have 15 apps monitoring 15 FB Pages legitimately as an admin. We grab data once an hour, then process posts and comments based on hashtags. It has been running for about 2 months.  Once every few days one of the apps will get this error. Next time it runs (via a scheduled task) the error is gone. Some serious FB api gremlins

Comment: Yep, the fact that my (essentially useless) answer has a number of upvotes suggests that several others have encountered these odd, intermittent issues with the Facebook API...

Answer (score 5):

I think I can shed a little more light on this.

I get this return often when making a request for the Page specific access tokens; failures on this call seem to be proportional to the number of Page's that are administered by the account for which the access token is for, so if you admin 100 pages, you will fail more often than if you have 1 pages, if you have a 5000 pages failures will happen more often than they don't.

This indicates that the failure is related to the response size, as the JSON returned can be very lengthy for large sets of Page's.

The fix for this is simple.  Instead of requesting all of the Page's using

`http://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={admin access token}`

use

`http://graph.facebook.com/{page id}?fields=access_token&access_token={admin access token}`

This will return the access token for just that page.  Because the response is small you should experience Facebook server-side errors much less frequently.  Since I switched I don't think I've ever experienced a failure and I make the call very often.

Comment: Thanks—I don't think this was the issue, as my test account was only administering one page, but +1 for pointing out a way to retrieve just the token for a specific page.

Comment: How would you get back the page ids to insert into the page specific call?  The only endpoint I know to do that is the accounts endpoint, and I'm getting the same error as the original poster when I hit the accounts endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE&expires_in=6483

Comment: I get the same error. Also, why would you pass in the `expires_in` property? Surely that's a read-only parameter that would be set by Facebook when issuing the token?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark as it starts suddenly all of a sudden, I was getting this error while posting some open graph actions and objects on my facebook timeline, but the issue I discovered was basically with the cache facebook maintains.

I made some "og" meta-tags changes in my object URLs (talking about Open Graph objects here), and somehow facebook was giving the same error as mentioned in the main question because it was not taking the changes on refreshing my page completely. Then, to refresh those from the facebook side, I had to just debug my object URLs (both 'http' and 'https' ones) from [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and voila !

Answer (score 0):

This is error [code 2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/error-handling). Simply retry after a few of seconds. In Laraval you can use the [retry()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/error-handling) helper function as such:

```php
try {
    $response = retry(3, function () use ($fb, $accessToken) {
        return $fb->get('/123123123/media?fields=id', $accessToken);
    }, 3000);
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

This will retry 3 times in 3 second intervals. If the 3rd time fails it'll throw.

Answer (score 0):

## This May Solve Your Issue.

### It solved mine, fast.

So, I tried to access this **Instagram Basic Display API** (It can solve this problem on **Facebook/Instagram Graph API** too) from this end-point:
[https://graph.instagram.com/{user-id}?fields=id,username&access_token={access-token}](https://graph.instagram.com/%7Buser-id%7D?fields=id,username&access_token=%7Baccess-token%7D)

Got this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
        "type": "OAuthException"
    }
}
```

Soon enough I discovered that I was using my Instagram ID but what I should have been using is **Facebook User ID**.

This is what **solved** my issue, **I was using the wrong user ID**

For anyone that is coming from Instagram API you can get from this link information about your user:
[https://www.instagram.com/{user-name}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Buser-name%7D/?__a=1)

There you can find Facebook User ID.