# Facebook error: "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Starting last Friday, 7/13, we've been getting the "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later." error for our OG Graph object posts. With the same API post rate, our error rate for these API calls went from 0.13% to 65% (less than 1% to 65%) within about a minute. Saturday it dropped to about 46%, and it's currently at 28%.

We normally have these automatically retried, but we had to disable that when the error rate rose because it choked our queue.

If we manually retry any of the failed ones, they fail every time with this error.

This seems to be happening only for one of our OG action/object combos - "earn medal".  All our other combos work fine with manual testing.

Since our error rate jumped suddenly, is very high, and retrying doesn't work, something obviously seems wrong.

Could we be over a rate limit?  Did something happen to our "medal" OG Object?

Comment: I'm all of a sudden seeing this as well, not sure why it's happening.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8353119/470749

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more manual testing, we realized this was only happening for a specific instance of our "medal" OG Object (id 4). Others worked fine. So we tried some of those instances (ids 1 through 5) in [FB's URL debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), and they all parsed fine.

Then tried to post those medals again manually, and id 4 then worked every time.

It seems like FB automatically scraped our OG Objects last Friday, and the medal id 4 object request failed for some reason, causing that object's cache to disappear on FB's end.

So if you see a sudden, large increase in OG Object API call errors, try manually re-caching the object instances that failed.

Answer (score 2):

It's worthing noting this error can occur somewhat randomly without reasonable cause.  I've seen this many times when fetching facebook posts for a page depending on the limit parameter.  If I ask for facebook posts of a page with limit 100, I'll get the error:

```
{
  error: {
    message: "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
    type: "OAuthException",
    is_transient: true,
    code: 2
  }
}
```

If I ask for it with limit 2, I won't get the error.  You may be thinking a timeout could cause this.  It's possible because I've seen that before (when you request a ton of data) but in this case increasing the limit to 3 also causes the error.  `limit=2` is fine while `limit=3` causes the above error.  That's a bug

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution about eight hours and in my case was the problem with name "*An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.*" in a **bad PAGE ID**... OMG

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you resolved this yet. I had this error message apear on my screen when trying to boost posts or do certain other things on Facebook. I finally figured out my spyware, Kaspersky Internet  Security, was interfering with the function. If you have this or another anti-virus program try temporarily disabling or pausing protection. This means you will be dealing with sensitive data without your anti-virus program, but your native firewalls and virus protections will still be in place. It is annoying... sometimes Kaspersky acts more like a virus than an anti-virus. Perhaps facebook support people can take note of this, too, as this may resolve the problem for the many who are having it and not finding solution through your suggested steps (for instance, with Kaspersky on, I cannot access ad manager either...)

Answer (score 0):

try this. it works for me

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q='. $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ;
$response = file_get_contents($url);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while posting some open graph actions and objects on my facebook timeline, but the issue I discovered was basically with the cache facebook maintains.

I made some "og" meta-tags changes in my object URLs (talking about Open Graph objects here), and somehow facebook was giving the same error as mentioned in the main question because it was not taking the changes on refreshing my page completely. Then, to refresh those from the facebook side, I had to just debug my object URLs (both 'http' and 'https' ones) from [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and voila !

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing, and if I change the server that sent the request, and therefore change the machine and IP address, the same data are taken is facebook.