# Facebook Page feed not accessible via JS SDK nor Graph API

Tags: facebook

I'm recently experiencing troubles with a company page at Facebook. I used to access the https://graph.facebook.com/[page alias]/feed url (providing an access token of course). It has been working for months now and it suddenly stopped.

The JSON I get is the following:
{
    message: "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
    type: "OAuthException",
    code: 2
}

It stopped working the day/night after the page posted a status containing a link (in terms of Facebook graph), and also it contained 3 bit.ly links. I have the assumption that the (whole!) feed got blocked because of this, as this could be considered spamming ... It's a serious website, though!

Any tips on this? I found this on the internet: http://support.conversocial.com/entries/23482331-Known-issue-Facebook-Shortened-URLs-such-as-bit-ly

My advice would be to remove the post containing those links and - hope - that it gets "enabled" at some time - but it would be disappointing if not, of course :)

Comment: Did you debugged the token in [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)?

Comment: There's something wrong with the Graph API. Has happened to me as well, but the thing started working fine suddenly. Also, take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353119/facebook-api-oauthexception-an-unexpected-error-has-occurred-please-retry-you). So, I think you should wait and it'll be fine in a few days. Please do share if you find something. This strange behavior must have an explanation.

Comment: @SahilMittal yes, I did use the debugger with some access tokens (also with the app-token, so not a user-specific one) and I got the same error with all of them.

Fun fact: it's working again since a few hours! So: just ... wait! It will be back some time! Maybe this thread helps someone in the future though ;-)